# How can I use param as a key

Tags: javascript

Example,

```
function setLocalStorage(key, value){
            localStorage.key = value;
}
```

i want the key param to be the key, but if i code like this

the "key" string becomes the key.

Comment: Try something like `localStorage[key]=value;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to add a key to an object with a value:

```
function setLocalStorage(key, value){
    localStorage[key] = value;
}
```